# How to change dictionary keys in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

Given the following list of dictionaries:

```
[
     {'Label': 'Acura', 'Value': '1'}, 
     {'Label': 'Agrale', 'Value': '2'}
]
```

How can I replace the word 'Label' with 'Make' and 'Value' with 'Code'?

I´m new to python and have tried many different approaches with no success.

Comment: Hi Hugo, could you please add the code of your "different approaches" at least one approach. It will make your question more clearer, please also what you expect as output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `.pop`:

```
lst = [{'Label': 'Acura', 'Value': '1'}, {'Label': 'Agrale', 'Value': '2'}]

for d in lst:
    d['Make'] = d.pop('Label')
    d['Code'] = d.pop('Value')

print(lst)
```

This yields

```
[{'Make': 'Acura', 'Code': '1'}, {'Make': 'Agrale', 'Code': '2'}]
```

If the key happens to not exist. you could define a default key as well:

```
d['new_key'] = d.pop('missing_key', 'default_value')
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to add a new key with the old value, and then delete the old key:

```
mydict['Make'] = mydict['Label']
del mydict['Label']
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([{'Label': 'Acura', 'Value': '1'}, {'Label': 'Agrale', 'Value': '2'}])
df=df.rename(index=str, columns={"Label": "Make", "Value": "Code"})
df.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: is pandas really necessary for this?

Comment: No, but it is easier and should be efficient for more number of columns. Operations like `pop()` are very costly

Comment: sorry but I didn't mention `pop`?